# Remove all files/directories except for one file

Tags: file-management

I have a directory containing a large number of files. I want to delete all files except for file.txt . How do I do this?

There are too many files to remove the unwanted ones individually and their names are too diverse to use * to remove them all except this one file.

Someone suggested using

```
rm !(file.txt)
```

But it doesn't work. It returns:

```
Badly placed ()'s
```

My OS is Scientific Linux 6.

Any ideas?

Comment: move the one you want to keep, then rm the others?

Comment: @OlivierDulac Are we the only two people in this question who aren't overthinking the question?

Comment: @shadur: well, I can relate to them: oneliners are attractive... ^^

Comment: Thanks, and yes I was looking for a one-line solution. It's too time consuming to keep moving files around as I have to do this quite often.

Comment: If your specifically want to preserve `.git` directory, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22347541/565877

Answer (score 471, accepted):

POSIXly:

```
find . ! -name 'file.txt' -type f -exec rm -f {} +
```

will remove all regular files (recursively, including hidden ones) except any files called `file.txt`. To remove directories, change `-type f` to `-type d` and add `-r` option to `rm`.

In `bash`, to use `rm -- !(file.txt)`, you must [enable extglob](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html#Pattern-Matching):

```
$ shopt -s extglob 
$ rm -- !(file.txt)
```

(or calling `bash -O extglob`)

Note that `extglob` only works in `bash` and Korn shell family. And using `rm -- !(file.txt)` can cause an `Argument list too long` error.

In `zsh`, you can use `^` to negate pattern with [extendedglob](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Operators) enabled:

```
$ setopt extendedglob
$ rm -- ^file.txt
```

or using the same syntax with `ksh` and `bash` with options `ksh_glob` and `no_bare_glob_qual` enabled.

Comment: Specifying the directory is good practice (fullpath in this case? or maybe add a warning here that this command deletes every file *starting from the current working directory* ?). I also usually write any example with `rm` as `echo rm` instead, and ask people to only take out the echo when they are really sure it will do what they want. Other than that, +1 for the thorough answer

Comment: I'd suggest `-delete` instead of `-exec`, shorter and easier to remember

Comment: @Izkata: `-delete` is not defined by POSIX.

Comment: How to exclude list of files?

Comment: @Meysam - see my answer for a solution that will handle a list of files. Else with Gnouc's `find` solution you can do `! \( -name one_file -o -name two_file \)` and so on.

Comment: If you use `rm -r`, you'll remove the directory that contains `file.txt`, which will effectively remove the file that you wanted to keep.

Comment: `rm !(file.txt)` 
working fine if there is no directories in same level with sub-files
`rm -rf !(file.tx)`
will solve this problem

Comment: To remove directories with `find`, change `rm` to `rmdir`, not `rm -r`.  `rmdir` won't delete a directory containing file(s), while `rm -r` will (thus deleting `file.txt`).  And **if** you are using GNU `rmdir`, you can also use its `--ignore-fail-on-non-empty` option.

Comment: @cas: It's about remove directory, not directory contain `file.txt`. Example remove all directories except directory `dir`, then the command is `find . ! -name 'dir' -type d -exec rm -rf {} +`. And also, the search is limited to 1 level only.

Comment: @cuonglm ,its better if anyone explain why `+`  at the end because i've often see `;`

Comment: I have to use `find . ! -name 'basejit-cli.sh' ! -name '.' ! -name '..' -exec rm -rf {} +` to avoid trying to remove `.` and `..` on macOS.

Comment: @haxpor: `rm` won't remove `.` and `..`, so you can ignore, If you want it explicitly, do as you did, but not sure why `..` include there. At least in my El Capital, `find .` won't list `..`

Comment: To not include sub-directories, add `-maxdepth 1`.

Comment: @LoMaPh `-maxdepth` is not POSIX.

Comment: How do I remove files recursively, while ignoring a specified directory, such as `./documents`?

Comment: @leetbacoon See my answer above, using `type -d` and `rm -r`.

Comment: @Belalmazlom How can I exclude multiple files in case where I have files and folders in same current directory ? Something like this `rm -rf !(file1.txt|file2.txt|..)` is possible ?

Comment: This doesn't work with symlinks. It also deletes the files pointed to by symlinks.

Comment: What does `--` do after `rm`?

Comment: Could this solution applied for the folders as well?

Comment: @alper Yes, quote from my answer: "To remove directories, change -type f to -type d and add -r option to rm."

Comment: Be careful on the copy and past!

Comment: I used `rm -r !(file.txt)`. No need for `rm -- -r !(file.txt)` because the `--` is used to indicate the end of command options so that `rm` can remove a file whose name starts with a `-`. For example `-foo` in this command `rm -- -foo`. Besides `rm -- -r !(file.txt)` wouldn't work as intended because `-r` will be treated as a file name, since it follows `--`.

Answer (score 193):

Another take in a different direction (iff there are no spaces in file names)

```
ls | grep -xv "file.txt" | xargs rm
```

or (works even if there are spaces in file names)

```
ls | grep -xv "file.txt" | parallel rm
```

from `man grep`:

```
 -v, --invert-match
          Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.  (-v is specified by POSIX)

 
 -x, --line-regexp
          Select  only  those  matches  that exactly match the
          whole line.  For a regular expression pattern,  this
          is   like   parenthesizing   the  pattern  and  then
          surrounding it with ^ and $.
```

Without the `-x` we'd keep `my-file.txt` as well.

Comment: It will not work if file names have a space ...

Comment: Ciao @Matteo, it works for files with spaces too, but you need to surround the grep-pattern by quotes, e.g. `ls | grep -v "a file with spaces.bin" | xargs rm`. This is normal `grep` syntax.

Comment: @Sebastian The problem is not the `grep` but `rm`. `rm` will get a list of space separated arguments. Try `touch 'a b'; touch 'c d'; ls | grep -v 'a b' | xargs rm`: you will get `rm: c: No such file or directory` and `rm: d: No such file or directory`

Comment: Yes, this is a common problem. See the options `-print0` in `find` and `-0` in `xargs`. Here is a workaround, but is is slightly inconvenient. `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | grep -v 'a b' | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 rm`. By the way, gnu `parallel` handles this well (I almost always use it as a substitute for xargs: `ls | grep -v 'a b' | parallel rm`

Comment: It's not only spaces, it's all blanks and newlines, but also quoting characters (single, double quotes and backslash) and filenames starting with `-`.

Comment: It's good solution where shopt or find does not work as in here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/153863/35004. Prefer shopt / find with xargs to keep things resource-efficient.

Comment: Worked for me in OSX with bash and zsh. TY!

Comment: This worked for me `ls -Q | grep -v file.txt | xargs rm -fr` . -Q switch is "enclose entry names in double quotes"

Comment: @kuzyn: Wow, you learn something new every day. Nice

Comment: awesome answer and usage of the `-v` flag. see the link for not deleting multiple files instead of just one using grep with the `-v` and `-E` flag. https://stackoverflow.com/a/5464614/708807

Comment: The dot character into the `grep` search pattern is matching any character if it is not escaped like `'file\.txt'` to match literal dot only. For example, it will also match a file named `filestxt`.

Comment: `xargs -d '\n'` also works for the spaces in filenames

Comment: With coreutils 8.30 on Kubuntu 20.04, `ls` automatically quotes filenames that have spaces in them.

Answer (score 51):

Maintain a copy, delete everything, restore copy:

```
{   rm -rf *
    tar -x
} <<TAR
$(tar -c $one_file)
TAR
```

In one line:

```
{ rm -rf *; tar -x; } <<< $(tar -c $one_file)
```

But that requires a shell that supports here-strings.

Comment: This is somewhat mind-blowing.

Comment: But if this gets interrupted halfway through, or if anything else goes wrong, the file is gone.

Comment: @kasperd - no. Only if the parent shell dies between the time it runs `rm` and `tar -x`. `rm` can fail as much as it wants.

Comment: Isn't more efficient to move it to another directory and move it back? We don't need to deal with the content of the file, only with its path.

Comment: @leonboy - probably, but if youre crossing filesystems, it makes no difference

Comment: Just seen your one line version @mikeserv , wow it's a bit above my head though, but I tried it and it certainly works.

Comment: @Derek - it's really not that crazy. POSIX requires that a shell redirect its input to the command you specify when it encounters a here-document. The command-substitution has to complete before anything else happens. Most shells use temp-files for here-docs - some pipes. Either way `tar -c` completes and the shell stashes its output before `rm` runs. Because `rm` ignores `stdin` its left hanging for `tar -x` when `rm` finishes - and the shell can divest itself of the copy it saved of your file(s). Here-docs can be used like aimed pipes a lot of the time.

Comment: That would only work with `zsh` as the output of tar will typically contain NUL bytes. Even then, you'd have trouble with files whose content end in empty lines and align with tar block size.

Comment: What if the file is 64GB in size? Or is there no actual copying involved?

Comment: @Zimano at best guess, it would read the file(s) into ram, and write it(them) back as a new file(s). I would expect this is harder on the hardware than not touching the file at all or just "moving" the file on a modern filesystem

Comment: @mikeserv I was hoping to do something more complex near the rm, for example <strike>`{ git ls-files -z | xargs -0 rm -rf ; tar -x; } <<< $(tar -c $one_file)`</strike> but i think that causes the tar to not redirect properly, thoughts?

Comment: @thorsummoner yeah. ive heard of thoughts. i think theyre something like this, but ive been wrong before!

Comment: This answer needs more English.

Answer (score 42):

you're all overthinking this.

```
cd ..
mv fulldir/file.txt /tmp/
rm -rf fulldir
mkdir fulldir
mv /tmp/file.txt fulldir/
```

Done.

**EDIT** Actually, easier:

```
cd ..
ln fulldir/file.txt ./
rm -rf fulldir
mkdir -p fulldir
mv file.txt fulldir/
```

Comment: that's the same thing my answer does. exce[pt it doesn't lose any permissions on the dir.

Comment: If it's a large file on a separate filesystem from /tmp and you're trying to remove everything from the root of the filesystem down, then moving it somewhere safe may not be an option.

Comment: This is definitely the simplest answer.

Comment: Both fail if `fulldir` is a mountpoint. Both result in incorrect settings if `fulldir` isn't "your" directory with standard permissions

Comment: This seems like the best answer if you have minimal shell experience.

Comment: Would it be possible to wrap this as a simple `function` that accepts 1 parameter for the files/directories you want to preserve?

Comment: Also, I wonder if someone out there knows how to preserve directory permissions.. feels like there must be a way.. Either way, `mv`ing files outside directory, and then obliterating contents in some way, seems like the best, safest, most obvious approach. Maybe everyone on this StackExchange is really good with shell scripts.

Answer (score 26):

On my Scientific Linux 6 OS this works:

```
shopt -s extglob
rm !(file.txt)
```

I also have Debian 32bit installed on a Virtual Machine. The above does not work but the following does:

```
find . -type f ! -name 'file.txt' -delete
```

Comment: You mean the `find` solution I gave didn't working?

Comment: "didn't work" or " isn't working". Yes your find solution also works. Thanks.

Comment: Can you make it more details? How "didn't work? It does not remove other files, or it removed `file.txt` or anything else?

Comment: I meant that on the Debian OS "$rm !(file.txt)" returns "Badly placed ()'s". So I tried "$shopt -s extglob", but it returned: "shopt: Command not found". Then I tried the "find" solution. It does work.

Comment: `$` is shell prompt in my answer, you must remove it in your actual command. And what shell do you use in `Debian`?

Comment: I did not include the $ prompt. I use a tcsh shell in Debian.

Comment: Oh, so of course it doesn't work. `shopt` is not a `tcsh` builtin.

Answer (score 13):

I find that this approach is very simple, works, and doesn't require any special extensions (that I know of!)

```
ls --hide=file.txt | xargs -d '\n' rm
```

Comment: The simple solution for files **without new lines, quotes and such**

Answer (score 11):

Use `rm !("file.txt")` instead of `rm !(file.txt)`

Comment: That makes absolutely no difference whatsoever. The issue here was that the OP was 1) not using a shell that supports this format and 2) even in bash, you need to enable it with `shopt -s extglob`. In any case, quoting a simple filename like that would have made no difference.

Comment: To keep just utils folder do - rm -rf !("utils")

Answer (score 8):

Just to give a different answer, you can use the default behavior of `rm` that it won't delete folders:

```
mkdir tmp && mv file.txt tmp  # create tmp dir and move files there
rm                            # delete all other files
mv tmp/* . && rm -rf tmp      # move all files back and delete tmp dir
```

Comment: What would this do if ./tmp already exists as a file or, worse, as a directory with things already in it? Using `dirr=mktemp && mv file.txt "$dirr"; rm; mv "$dirr/*" . && rm -rf "$dirr"` would avoid this issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I needed to remove all files and folder except for zip files, inspired on accepted answer (I gave of course a +1), while from folder I want to clean all except zip files I use `find . ! -name '*.zip' ! -name '.' ! -name '..'  -exec rm -rf {} +`, for example (all files/folders are empty since created just for the example):

```
my-computer:/tmp/toclean>ll
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 user users 0 Oct  4 10:47 aaa.zip
-rw-r--r-- 1 user users 0 Oct  4 10:47 tata
drwxr-xr-x 1 user users 0 Oct  4 10:47 titi
drwxr-xr-x 1 user users 0 Oct  4 10:47 tutu
-rw-r--r-- 1 user users 0 Oct  4 10:47 yoyo
-rw-r--r-- 1 user users 0 Oct  4 10:47 zzz.zip
my-computer:/tmp/toclean>find . ! -name '*.zip' ! -name '.' ! -name '..'  -exec rm -rf {} +
my-computer:/tmp/toclean>ll
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 user users 0 Oct  4 10:47 aaa.zip
-rw-r--r-- 1 user users 0 Oct  4 10:47 zzz.zip
```

Note I exclude `'.'` and `'..'` to just to avoid `rm: refusing to remove '.' or '..' directory: skipping '.'` message.