# Cat files except one

Tags: text-processing, cat

I'm looking for something to concatenate all files with given extension within a directory, except one. Like:

```
cat *.txt !(DISCARD.txt)  > catKEPT
```

This should concatenate all *.txt files in directory, except DISCARD.txt.

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/153863/38906

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -iname '*.txt' -not -name 'DISCARD.txt' -exec cat {} +>catKEPT
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `bash` (most of the time this is the case), you may use the `extglob` shell option that will extend your shell with a more powerful pattern matching syntax.

You can turn it on with `shopt -s extglob`, and turn it off with `shopt -u extglob`.

In your example, you would simply do:

```
$ shopt -s extglob
$ cat -- !(DISCARD).txt > catKEPT
```

You can find more about this command in this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216995/how-can-i-use-inverse-or-negative-wildcards-when-pattern-matching-in-a-unix-linu/217208#217208).

Comment: I tried it, but command got stuck (no output)

Comment: Are you sure you have `bash` ? Try `echo $SHELL` to know what shell you are using.

Comment: OP wants to cat only `.txt` files so you'll have to use the glob like this: `cat -- !(DISCARD).txt`