# Why rm exclude using ! doesn't work in zsh?

Tags: zsh, wildcards

I have 10 files in current directory:

```
10test
1test
2test
3test
4test
5test
6test
7test
8test
9test
```

I want to remove all file except `2test` and `3test`, but I run command `rm !(2test|3test)` doesn't work. I get the following error:

```
zsh: no matches found: !(2test|3test)
```

Comment: Use `^(2test|3test)`, `!` works for bash, zsh however uses `^`.

Comment: I just tried  `rm ^(2test|3test)`, still doesn't work

Comment: `touch {1..10}test; rm ^(2test|3test)` leaves only the two files. If it doesn't work for you please provide your zsh version. Also make sure you use `setopt extendedglob` which is required for this to work.

Comment: zsh 5.0.8 (x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0)

Comment: You [need to `setopt kshglob` to enable `!(...)`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#ksh_002dlike-Glob-Operators).

Comment: Your version is fine, make sure you set `extendedglob`.

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/153863/38906

Comment: @Marco, thanks set `extendedglob` works for `rm ^(2test|3test)`, but still doesn't work for 'rm !(2test|3test)`, what's the difference between `^` and `!`, why some online post says to use `!`??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`!(pattern)` is `ksh` glob syntax, in `zsh`, you use `^(pattern)` to negate the matching when `extendedglob` enabled:

```
setopt extendedglob
print -rl -- ^(2test|3test)
```

If you want to use `ksh` syntax, you need to enable `kshglob`:

```
setopt kshglob
print -rl -- !(2test|3test)
```

You can also use the *and-not*/*except* operator:

```
setopt extendedglob
print -rl -- *test~[23]*
```

(`*test` files except those that start with `2` or `3`).

Also not that unless the `nobareglobqual` option is enabled or you use `|`s within them, trailing `(...)` glob grouping operators conflict with glob qualifiers. For example, in `!(foo)` or `^(foo)`, the `foo` would be treated as a glob qualifier. You'd need `^foo` or `!(foo)(#q)` (the `(#q)` adds a non-bare (explicit) glob qualifier).

Comment: I am using zshell, `^` works for normal files, but it doesn't work for dot files. imagine I have a bunch of dot files. `.a, .b, .c, .d ...` . I want to remove all of them but keep `.a` and `.b`, using `rm ^(.a|.b)` doesn't work. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: You need to use `D` qualifier to include dot file in globbing result, try `print -rl -- ^(.a|.d)(D)`

Answer (score 6):

When you use `setopt extendedglob` you can use `^(2test|3test)` to remove all files except `2test` and `3test`:

```
# setopt extendedglob
# touch {1..10}test
# rm ^(2test|3test)
# ls
2test 3test
```

`!` is used by bash, zsh however uses `^`.

Answer (score 0):

starting with a clean (empty) zsh

```
 zsh -f 
 setopt extendedglob
 touch {1..10}test
 rm ^(2|3)test(.)
```