# find: delete folder and sub folders but add exception to two files

Tags: linux, files, find

I am trying to use the `find` command to do the following:
Delete a whole folder with files, folders and subfolders except for 2 files, here is an example of what I need:

```
 test/folder1/file1.txt
 test/folder1/file2.txt
 test/folder1/subfolder1/
 test/folder1/subfolder1/file3.txt
 test/folder1/subfolder1/subfolder2/file4.txt
 test/folder2/file5.txt
 test/folder3/file6.txt
```

I need to delete everything except for `file2.txt` and `file3.txt`

Here is what I already did

```
 find /test* ! -path '/test/folder1/file2.txt' -a ! -path 'test/folder1/subfolder1/file3.txt'
```

This will list me all the files except the ones I specified. However if I add `-exec rm -rf {}` by the end of the command it will delete everything.

I have also tried this other command and didn't work

```
rm -r  test/folder1/ !(file2.txt|file3.txt)
```

I don't know much about regular expression so I am trying to make it work by testing commands I found online, however none of them seems to be working.

Comment: I'd suggest two passes - a 'find -type f' that calls a simple "-delete" on the files that you want to remove. Then run a 'find -type d' with  an 'exec rmdir' (keeping your exclusions intact for both runs).

Comment: [`{ rm -rf test/*; tar -x; } <<< $(tar -c test/**/file1 test/**/file2.txt)`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/153869) with `zsh` or `bash` + `shopt -s globstar`

Answer (score 1):

Don't call `rm -rf`. As soon as you run it on a directory, that deletes all the files in the directory and the subdirectories, even the ones you wanted to keep. More generally, don't call `rm -rf` unless you know why a simple `rm` won't do. Here, `rm -f` is warranted if you want to be sure that your script won't ask for confirmation to delete a read-only file, but `-r` is clearly not warranted.

To just delete the files:

```
find /test* ! -path '/test/folder1/file2.txt' -a ! -path 'test/folder1/subfolder1/file3.txt' -a -exec rm -f {} +
```

If you also want to delete the directories that become empty, call `rmdir` on them. Use `-depth` so that the directory contents are considered before the directory itself.

```
find /test* ! -path '/test/folder1/file2.txt' -a ! -path 'test/folder1/subfolder1/file3.txt' -a \( -type d rmdir {} \; -o -exec rm -f {} \; \)
```

You'll get errors from `rmdir` running on non-empty directories, they're annoying but harmless.

If your find has `-delete` and `-empty` (e.g. GNU find), you don't need to call `rm` and `rmdir`.

```
find /test* ! -path '/test/folder1/file2.txt' -a ! -path 'test/folder1/subfolder1/file3.txt' -a ! -type d ! -empty -delete
```

Answer (score 0):

Look, I also don't know offhand how to do it with `find` options but you can also use shell scripting in you `find`:

First delete files:

```
 find . -type f -exec bash -c \
    ' [[ "{}" == "./test/folder1/file2.txt" || \
         "{}" == "./test/folder1/subfolder1/file3.txt" ]] \
      || rm "{}" ' \;
```

And then delete all not empty folders:

```
find .  -type d -exec rmdir {} \; 2>/dev/null
```