# how to remove all files exclude specific files

Tags: linux, shell-script, rhel, find, rm

Under **/var/log/hive** we have a lot of log files

we want to remove all files exclude the following that should be not removed

```
hivemetastore.log
hiveserver2-report.json.tmp
hivemetastore-report.json.tmp
```

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/153862/remove-all-files-directories-except-for-one-file

Comment: we have couple files to exclude , this post talk about one file to exclude

Comment: this is not duplicate as I mentioned the post talk about one file for exclude and I need couple file to exclude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the question 153862 mentioned by Kamaraj, use find. Just use multiple entries of `! -name`:

```
$ ls
hivemetastore.log  hivemetastore-report.json.tmp  hiveserver2-report.json.tmp  1  2  3  4
$ find . ! -name 'hivemetastore.log' ! -name 'hivemetastore-report.json.tmp' ! -name 'hiveserver2-report.json.tmp' -type f -exec rm -f {} +
$ ls
hivemetastore.log  hivemetastore-report.json.tmp  hiveserver2-report.json.tmp
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

To get the list of files other than `hivemetastore.log ,hiveserver2-report.json.tmp, hivemetastore-report.json.tmp` :

```
find  /var/log/hive -type f ! -name "hivemetastore.log" ! -name "hiveserver2-report.json.tmp" ! -name "hivemetastore-report.json.tmp" -print
```

To delete and get the list of deleted files:

```
find  /var/log/hive -type f ! -name "hivemetastore.log" ! -name "hiveserver2-report.json.tmp" ! -name "hivemetastore-report.json.tmp" -delete -print
```

Answer (score 0):

Going off of @Kamaraj's comment - you can use `find` to look for multiple files using the `-o` switch, and then negate it and use `-exec` to `rm` the rest.

List all files except the ones named:

```
find . -type f ! \( -name 'hivemetastore.log' -o -name 'hiveserver2-report.json.tmp' -o -name 'hivemetastore-report.json.tmp' \)
```

Chain an `exec` to `rm` those files:

```
find . -type f ! \( -name 'hivemetastore.log' -o -name 'hiveserver2-report.json.tmp' -o -name 'hivemetastore-report.json.tmp' \) -exec rm -f {} +
```